# Deactivate ligatures in small caps in xelatex

Tags: xetex, fontspec, small-caps, ligatures, opentype

In the following minimal example using the Palatino Linotype font:

```
\documentclass[twoside]{book}
\usepackage{mathspec}
\setmainfont{PalatinoLinotype}[
   Extension      = .ttf,
   Ligatures      = TeX,
   WordSpace      = {1.1,1.1,1.0},
   UprightFont={PalatinoLinotype},
   ItalicFont={PalatinoLinotypeItalic},
   Numbers        = Lining,
   Scale          = 0.95
]
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{french}
\begin{document}

\Huge

Battra

\textsc{Battra}

\end{document}
```

I get a (regular) tt ligature inside a small caps string:

[image]

which is not normal since in the font there is a `liga` table with a `sub t t by t_t;` substitution, but this substitution does not apply to the small caps glyph, which is called `T.c2sc`. Indeed, I did the same in Illustrator, and here is what I got:

[image]

So it is not the fault of the font, but rather of `fontspec`. How can I resolve this issue?

Unfortunately I use small caps mainly for author names in bibliography (as is the French custom) so I can hardly go into the BIB data and add a `\/` command to separate all the tt and tz letter pairs, it will spoil my alphabetical ordering. And I don't want to remove the tt, tz ligatures from the Palatino font, it's part of its (invisible for the common mortal) charms. Can you give me a solution on the `fontspec` level? Maybe some way to deactivate `liga` ligatures only when in small caps?

For information, here is the `liga` table of the font:

```
feature liga {
# GSUB feature: Standard Ligatures
# Lookups: 1

  script latn; # Latin
  sub f b by f_b;
  sub f f b by f_f_b;
  sub f f h by f_f_h;
  sub f f i by f_f_i;
  sub f f k by f_f_k;
  sub f f l by f_f_l;
  sub f f by f_f;
  sub f h by f_h;
  sub f i by fi;
  sub f j by f_j;
  sub f k by f_k;
  sub f l by fl;
  sub t t by t_t;
  sub t z by t_z;
    language TRK ; # Turkish
    language ROM ; # Romanian

} liga;
```

None of them is appropriate for small caps…

**I noticed something peculiar: this problem occurs for the tt and tz ligatures, but not for the usual fi, ff, fl, ffi, ffl. I guess that the latter ones are covered by the `Ligatures = TeX` option in `fontspec`, for some reason tt and tz are not correctly processed…**

Comment: `SmallCapsFeatures={Ligatures=Commonff}` could work (but untested as I don't have the font). But it looks a bit like a font problem. What happens with lualatex? (you will have to replace mathspec by fontspec to test this).

Comment: I can’t duplicate your bug with version 5.03 of Palatino Linotype and TeX Live 2020. You appear to have a version of the font named `PalatinoLinotype.ttf` rather than `PALA.TTF`. What version number does `otfinfo -i PalatinoLinotype.ttf` report?

Comment: I’m not sure which one that is, since the version that ships with MS Windows and Office is `PALA.TTF` and the version sold at Linotype’s website is `pala_M.ttf`.

Comment: It's `Family:              Palatino Linotype
Subfamily:           Regular
Full name:           PalatinoLinotype-Roman
PostScript name:     PalatinoLinotype-Roman
Version:             Version 5.00
Unique ID:           Version 5.00;LINO;PalatinoLinotype-Roman;1996;FL720`, the version provided in MacOS X.

Comment: When I type `SmallCapsFeatures={Ligatures=Commonff},` I get the error message `LaTeX3 Error: Key 'fontspec-opentype/Ligatures' accepts only a fixed set of
(LaTeX3)        choices.`

Comment: @yannis It’s a typo for `Ligatures=CommonOff`.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don’t have a Mac to test a solution, but it looks like you have an earlier version of the font. I recall those had some coding errors, such as mapping small-caps `i` to a dotted `İ` in all languages, not just Turkish.

Comment: It works! Thanks! Maybe you can transform the comment into an answer so that I can validate it?